# Как передать любое значение из delphi в HTML страницу.

Tags: html, delphi

Как передать любое значение из delphi в HTML страницу:

1. С использованием фреймворка UniGui?
2. С использованием IntraWeb?
3. С использованием WebBroker/WebSnap?

Не нашел в интернете, хотябы скиньте пример!

Comment: Можно, стандартный компонент TWebBrowser, через `#info` url, можно через `?info` в урле url. Можно через JavaScript `webbrowser1.Document.Scripts`. Можно через `navigate("javascript:javafn();")`. Можно напрямую в div или кнопки.

Comment: Нужно параметр в страницу передать или значение в контрол веб-страницы? Можно уточнение написать для конкретной задачи?

Comment: Скинь пример пожалуйста по всем, что перечислил.

Answer (score 0):

Делай вот так:

```
var
  col: IHTMLElementCollection;
  el: IHTMLInputElement;
  FSum: integer;
begin
    FSum := 100;
    col := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementsByName('amount');
    el := col.item(0, 0) as IHTMLInputElement;
    el.value := IntToStr(FSum);
end;
```